# Rails admin and has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin

I am using the [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) gem. And I have the following two models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :experiences
end


class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :city_id, :price, :title, :user_id
  attr_accessible :categories

  validates :title, :description, :user_id, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

In the Rails admin, I am not able to add a category to an existing Experience.  In the edit site of a particular Experience, I see this:

[image: Experience can't add category]

As you can see I can't select any categories, even though I have several categories created.

Comment: In category form. Do you can set the experience? Or is just in one side of association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was solved by adding the following into the Experience model:

```
attr_accessible :category_ids
```

instead of

```
attr_accessible :categories
```